# Postgresql multiple queries or case

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a two tables like

```
Id   date1.  date2. status.   code
1.   ....  ........   1.      AB110
2.   ....... .....    2.      AB001
3.   ....... .......  1.      AB120
4.   ...... ........  1.      AB111
```

And table2

```
Code.      Name.     Display
AB110     Abc.        Y
AB001     Xyx.        Y
```

I want something like this:

```
withdate.  type1.  type2.     code.   name
   2         1.        1      AB110.  Abc
   1.        2.        3      AB001.  Xyz
   3.  .     1.        2      AB120.  Lol
   1.        1         5      AB111.  Zzz
```

```
Select code, 
       table2.name, 
       count(case when date1 is not null then id) as withdate, 
       count(case when status=1 then id) as type1, 
       count(case when status=2 then id) as type2 
from table, table2 
where table.code=table2.code 
group by code, name
```

Is it rigth to write a query like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is right to write a query like that. The logic is good, but there is a synthax error in the case. I will prefer you count using the `sum` aggregate function as below.

```
select code, 
       table2.name, 
       sum(date1 is not null) as withdate, 
       sum(status=1) as type1, 
       sum(status=2) as type2 
from table, table2 
where table.code=table2.code 
group by code, name;
```

This way when date1 is not null 1 is added to the cummated value of the sum else zero is added which is like counting.

Comment: Any advantage of sum aggregate over count ?

Comment: None I can think of in terms of performance, but the code is shorter and clearer using sum instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct to me, except for the fact you forgot to fully qualify you column names and forgot the `end` keywords in the `case` expressions. There are, however, some improvements you could perform.

First, you shouldn't use implicit joins (having more than one table in the `from` clause) - they have been considered deprecated for quite a few years, and you should use a `join` clause.

Second, you didn't mention what version you were using, but Postgres 9.4 introduced a `filter` clause that can save you some of the boiler-plate of those `case` expressions.

```
SELECT   table1.code, 
         table2.name, 
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE date1 IS NOT NULL) AS withdate, 
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 1) AS type1, 
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = 2) AS type2
FROM     table1
JOIN     table2  ON table1.code = table2.code 
GROUP BY table1.code, table2.name
```